# I am getting a JavaScript alert in my project that I didn't create, threatening me?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, security

This morning I woke up to a JavaScript alert on a project of mine that runs [KnockoutJS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KnockoutJS), jQuery, and [Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/). It says "I can run any JavaScript of my choice on your users' browsers". The only third-party JavaScript I am downloading is [Typekit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typekit), and removing that does not make this go away. I've searched my JavaScript and vendor JavaScript and this string does not come back up matching anything.

How would you troubleshoot this and/or is this something that is known to occur?

Comment: It is injection not in your JS but in your DB :) You didn't sanitize user's input data

Comment: Are you importing any advertisements or something like that?  It's probably impossible to say without actually looking at the site.

Comment: Count yourself lucky they were nice about it, could've been much worse

Comment: Yeah, I would take that warning pretty seriously.

Comment: Not familiar with that message, but the sensible thing to do would be to remove all included javascript libraries and verify that it removes the message, then add them one at a time until it happens again.  If it happens without libraries, it's your browser and/or browser plugin that's causing it.

Comment: @Neil it could be a random user input too

Comment: @pomeh, you mean a hacker?  Yes, but it does him little good to freak out and run amok.

Comment: It ended up being a disgruntled member of the team trying to prove a point :)  Great, I"m an overworked developer still adding features in the middle of an unfinished project, with a team member trying to make me look bad.  The joys of group dynamics :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have a database for your application, that would be the next place to check. I'm guessing somebody found and exploited an Injection vulnerability (either un-sanitized HTML input or SQL)  and injected the script into a page via the database.

The last place would be to look at the ruby code to see if somehow a malicious user modified your source.

Comment: It may not even be sql injection, just unsanitized html injection.

Comment: @JayC - Was in the process of editting it when you commented. For some reason, I couldn't figure out what to call that vector. Thanks.

Comment: It was an unsanitized html injection attack, I'm using Mongo which apparently isn't susceptible to SQL injections.  But yeah, the sanitize gem does a nice job of cleaning up my input and now I don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 3):

You obviously take an input from user and then outputting it back as part of HTML without quoting or sanitizing. There's two quick checks to do:

1) Open source of page that outputs this alert and search inside source for exact text of alert - this should give you clear indication of what user-filled field is compromised.
2) To be sure, search all other fields in your database generated by users (login names, text of comments, etc.) for words "script" and "alert".

For future: always sanitize your input (remove HTML tags) before inserting it in HTML page OR escape symbols as entities according to standards OR explicitly treat is a plain text by assigning it to value of text node in DOM.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a hack attempt on your site. Check any databases, text files, etc. that are being used that are receiving user input. It sounds like you're not checking what's being posted to your server I'm guessing.